# Trying to open a JavaFX stage after calling Platform.exit()

Tags: java, javafx

I'm unable to create a new stage or launch application again after I call Platform.exit();

I'm calling Platform.exit() to return to code where I launched the JavaFX application

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = main
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:237)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:400)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:212)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:198)
    at com.m.Main.replaceSceneContent(Main.java:187)
    at com.m.Main.GotoMessage(Main.java:253)
```

Can anyone give me a gist what happens after I call Platform.exit()? Can't we relaunch the application?

Comment: Have you tried to override an `Application.stop()`? It'll be executed when you call `Platform.exit()`.

Comment: Why do you want to open a stage after calling Platform.exit?

Comment: @Puce I need to give a message to the user after it

Comment: You want to give a message to the user using JavaFX after shutting down JavaFX? What kind of message? Could provide it before shutting down JavaFX? Could you provide it in the log file?

Comment: User enters some details in the first scene which needs to be checked in the backend, so I call Platform.exit() here to return to the launch place, if the details are incorrect there will be message saying what detail is incorrect.@Puce

Comment: @SimY4 I'm not overriding it

Answer (score 6):

As the Javadoc says, Platform.exit() terminates the JavaFX Application Thread.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#exit--

Best is not to call Platform.exit() until you really want to shutdown JavaFX.
After shutting JavaFX down you would have to restart it using the Application.launch() method.
Better would be just to close the window, I guess.

Note that with `Platform.setImplicitExit(false);` you can prevent JavaFX from shutting down even if all windows are closed.

Comment: I need to return to the Application.launch place after I enter the form details. How can I achieve this without calling Platform.exit()?

Comment: You could call Application.launch in a separate thread and block the main thrad somehow until you have all necessary information. Or you could start Application.launch first and do other things in a background thread later. It really depends on many things...

Comment: This was a lifesaver! I have a JavaFX WebView that I use to get a cookie. After getting said cookie I close the window and load other elements. For some reason, between these operations, the JavaFX thread shuts down and I'd get a "toolkit has exited" exception. Calling Platform.setImplicitExit(false) solved my issue by preventing the JavaFX thread from shutting down when it's not supposed to.

Answer (score -2):

As the exception says...you're not on the FX application thread. Call `Platorm.exit()` on the thread using `Platform.runLater()`.

Comment: it's not helping me out @CAG

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. What is the issue? Unchanged? Something new?

Comment: After further review, I suspect I was mistaken in my answer but the only way to know is if I see some more source code, specifically related to the lines referenced in your exception.